# How to access a file shared by a file manager if my app does not have READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Tags: android, android-intent, android-permissions, intentfilter, android-external-storage

I write an Android app that exports some data to a file.

The file is published to the other apps via `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` and my custom `ContentProvider`. It works fine. A file can be attached to an e-mail or sent via `Bluetooth`.

Now, the other side of the same story is that the app should be able to receive a file to import it. My intention is to let the user select a file in a file manager and select the "Share" option. Now my `intent-filter` should be activated and my app should access the file.

My app does not have `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, because generally it does not need to access files in external storage. I do not want to add this permission, I do not to want to frighten users that my app can potentially access their photos and so on.

According to the documentation of the `Intent` class, if the calling app adds `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`, it should be enough to let my app read the shared file anyway.

My `intent-filter`:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

My code to process the Intent received through the intent-filter:

```
Uri uri = null;
if (uri == null)
{
    uri = intent.getData();
}
if (uri == null)
{
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.equals(intent.getAction()))
    {
        uri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM).get(0);
    }
    else
    {
        uri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    }
}
if (uri != null)
{
    try
    {
        InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        stream.read();
        stream.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Success " + intent.getAction() + " " + uri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error " + intent.getAction() + " " + uri.toString() + " " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

This is just a "test" code, so I just try to read anything from the start of the file to check if it works.

The result is:

- I tried using ES File Explorer and Amaze to "share" files to my app. Usually the received `Uri` is a file `Uri ("file://" scheme)` and trying to open this file fails on `openInputStream` with the information that my app does not have access to the file.
- When I share the file which is a media file from ES File Explorer for some reason the behavior changes. I receive a `"content://" Uri` and my app can access the file. Amaze still seems to send `"file://" Uri` and opening the file fails.
- I tried to modify the code to get the Uris from `ClipData` (if available) but it did not change anything.
- When I try to open an attachment from the built-in `MIUI` email client, I also receive `file:// Uris` and the file is not accessible. (to test this I had to use `ACTION_VIEW` action instead of `ACTION_SEND`)

I also tried the other way. I invoked a file picker from my app using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` `Intent` and wanted to use the returned `Uri` from my app. The result was even worse, because even `"content://" Uris` do not work.

**So the question is** - is there any way to access the files shared from the popular file managers in a way that allows my app to access the shared file without adding `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission`?

I can read in Android docs about `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` and that `file:// Uris` are forbidden starting from Android **7.0**, so everything is theoretically prepared to make it working, but in the real world I hit the wall...

I know I can always add `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to my app or ask the user to manually copy files to my app's external storage directory (path returned by `getExternalFilesDir`) and then access files there, but both these actions have serious drawbacks (security impact resulting from unnecessary permission or poor user experience).

Is there any other option that I can use to make it working?

Comment: `I invoked a file picker from my app using ACTION_GET_CONTENT Intent and wanted to use the returned Uri from my app. The result was even worse, because even "content://" Uris do not work`. Sorry. I do not understand what would not work. Your app can open the file using the content scheme. What do you want else?

Comment: The issue is that I cannot open content Uris in this case because the system says I do not have permission to do so. I suspect the picker app does not set FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION flag in the Intent sent back to my app, but I do not have source for ES File Explorer so I cannot verify this.

Comment: Hard to believe. I've never seen that a content scheme obtained by ACTION_GET_CONTENT is not usable. Why are you mentioning ES File Explorer while talking about ACTION_GET_CONTENT?

Comment: Because my app sends ACTION_GET_CONTENT with mime-type "application/*" (I don't want image files from the camera etc.) and CATEGORY_OPENABLE to the system (with a chooser in the middle). From the file managers I have installed on my phone (built-in MIUI file manager, ES File Explorer and Amaze) I noticed that only ES File Explorer sends back "content://" Uris sometimes (if a selected file is a media file). All the others seem to return "file://" scheme Uris only (at least I have not found any way to make them return content Uris).

Comment: And you are unable to open that content scheme?

Comment: No, I can't. Throws the exception. But if instead of sending ACTION_GET_CONTENT from my app I initiate the operation from ES File Explorer by selecting Share option and selecting my app as the target (my app has an intent-filter defined), the same content Uri opens successfully. Looks like ACTION_SEND intent sent by ES File Explorer has the correct security flag and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to the documentation of the Intent class, if the calling app adds FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION, it should be enough to let my app read the shared file anyway.

That only works for a `content` scheme.

> I invoked a file picker from my app using ACTION_GET_CONTENT Intent and wanted to use the returned Uri from my app. The result was even worse, because even "content://" Uris do not work.

There is a bug in your code, presumably. You might consider opening a separate Stack Overflow question for that.

Also, for API Level 19+, you can use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, which is the recommended `Intent` action.

> is there any way to access the files shared from the popular file managers in a way that allows my app to access the shared file without adding READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

Not if they give you a `file` `Uri`. And unfortunately `ACTION_SEND` does not offer filtering by scheme. :-(

Now, in the long term, `file` `Uri` values will fade out, as Android 7.0+ breaks apps that try to include them in an `Intent`, for apps with a `targetSdkVersion` of 24+.

Comment: Thanks for answering. So I guess, no luck so far... I need to wait until targetting Android 7.0+ becomes a standard. :)

Answer (score 0):

Android has introduced [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) class in support library for sharing files across other apps. This has been introduced for a security reasons.

Obviously in android 7.0 you cannot access the URIs with file prefix.

Unless and until the file mangers provide the URIs with 
**content://** instead of **file://,** you cannot access the files.